# Error: Invalid hook call. When trying to call hook... Followed suggested resolutions

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I'm getting this error when trying to use a hook

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

I checked and I do not have mismatching version and I do not have more than one copy of react in the same app
this is how I'm trying to use my hook.

This is how I'm trying to use my hook:

```
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging'





const Stack = createStackNavigator()






if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG)
}







export default function App() {


  // Request Push Notification permission from device.
const requestPermission = async () => {
  const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
  const enabled =
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED || authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

  if (enabled) {
    console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  requestPermission();
}, []);


  return ( 

...
...
...
```

I believe I'm using it correctly.. I'm not sure what else to check.

Comment: check if there is  a hook declared  above the line of export default function..

Comment: This is what I have above my export default function...

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator()






if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG)
}







export default function App() {


```

Answer (score 0):

Your useEffect code is inside of the inner function you need to place it outside of the function and make sure your useEffect is inside the main function.

Your Updated code Looks like this.

```
export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
  requestPermission();
}, []);

  // Request Push Notification permission from device.
const requestPermission = async () => {
  const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
  const enabled =
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED || authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

  if (enabled) {
    console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
  }
};




  return ( 

...
...
```

It's works fine.